# NSString rangeOfString issue when hidding keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, nsstring, uitextfield

I am implementing a list that can be filtered with the text from a `UITextField`, with the help of a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

The code is the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    _tempWrittenText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
    [self filterCountries];

    return YES;
}

/** Filter the countries with the currently typed text */
- (void) filterCountries {
    if (_tempWrittenText.length == 0) {
        _visibleCountriesList = (NSMutableArray*) _countriesList;
        [tableMedals reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 0] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    } else {
        _visibleCountriesList = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (Country* c in _countriesList) {
            if ([c.name rangeOfString: _tempWrittenText].location != NSNotFound) {
                [_visibleCountriesList addObject: c];
            }
        }
        [tableMedals reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 0] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
```

The filter works perfectly when typing on text; however, the **`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`** method is also fired when the *DONE* keyboard key is pressed (to hide the keyboard), which weirdly erases all items instead of leaving them as they are.

The issue is that the `rangeOfString` part is ALWAYS returning NSNotFound. I can't understand why, if I log the variables the two strings are correct.

For example: 
`[@"Angola" rangeOfString @"A"].location`   will give NSNotFound

And I repeat, this only happens when the keyboard is hidden. Anyone has an Idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, since `rangeOfString:` can't actually be conditionally failing to work properly, it's time to look more closely at the parameters themselves.

Comment: Well Logs didn't tell me much, but I re-reviewed and that was because the added character was a new line ("\n").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

is not fired when done button is pressed, otherwise if you force to call this function.

Use this to hide the keyboard, this will not trigger above method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the weird part. I just found that when Done key is pressed the system is adding a new line character, and that's why everything works bad.

Comment: I will choose your answer as accepted however in my program I don't really need to call resignFirstResponder to hide Keyboard, as I linked a function to the DidEndOnExit.

Comment: you are using UITextView and not UITextField, in that case you just trap the string on replacementString if it is new line

Comment: No, it really was a UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just found That the System adds a new line character when the Done key is pressed. I didn't know that was a default behavior or why it is doing so.

The way to prevent that is just to add the following:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
```

Hope that helps someone.